# Two columns, fixed fluid with 100% height

Tags: html, css, html-table, fixed-width

How can I achieve the following effect without the use of a table?

Example:
http://enstar.nl/example.php (The example may not be visible at the moment, the nameservers should have been changed, but my hosting isn't that fast in updating them. Should be working later today. I apologize for the inconvenience)

All methods require a header and/or a footer. I don't want that.

What I want is the following:

Pure CSS, no tables
2 columns, fixed fluid (in that order)
if the content hasn't reach the bottom of the viewport, than extend the columns to it. Else extent to the content (so like a sticky footer)

A table at 100%x100% does this naturally. But I really don't want to use a table for this.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Current HTML

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="navigation" valign="top" align="left">
        </td>
        <td id="content" valign="top" align="left">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

to set a two column there are a couple of options if you don't want to use tables

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="background-color: green;">
        <div id="leftCol" style="float: left; width: 200px;">testing</div>
        <div style="background-color: red; margin-left: 200px;">
            <div id="rightCol" style="height: 900px;" >testing testing testing testing testing testing testing</div>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as the text inside the rightCol is longer than that in the left col (which can be handled by a min-height on the element) then you shouldn't have any problems with it scaling.

This also nullifies the need for the Javascript to set the second width.  The reason is it is set to the width of the parent div which by default is 100% since you margin the red column left 200px it slides the display section over so you can see your left column.

Comment: If I set body and html to height 100%;, that one seems to work. But how do I get it to work with a fixed-fluid layout? If I edit column left to width: 200px;, how do I edit column right width?

See http://www.enstar.nl/example2.php

(Hmmz, I see my nameservers haven't changed yet, so the example may not be visible without changing your host file to the new IP.

They should be working within a few hours

Comment: What happens when content goes over the first page?

Comment: @nightfox89 The only real answer when you want a fixed column and then a left side to be a variable width you need to use javascript.  Please see the edits

Comment: @Jleagle I'm not sure what you mean by what happens when content goes over the first page. are you talking about theres more content than width or are you talking about initial render or what?

Comment: If content in one column became taller than the viewport, would it make one column taller than the other?

Comment: @Jleagle please take a look at my updated response.  I believe this is similar to a sprite style layout.

Comment: Hmm, the current examples have helped me understand it a bit more. But as far as I can see, I only have 2 options:

a) use table
b) use javascript

I have experience using javascript before, but it was to slow. You can see it lag while you resize the viewport. So I think I'm going to have to go with the table design. 1 table isn't such a sin, is it? ;)

Comment: @nightfox89 If you aren't worried about backwards compatibility then you could always use the table-column attribute but the support in IE didn't start until IE8

Comment: Wel, IE7 is a must. IE6 can stay down in hell