# Two columns layout with 100% height. One fixed column and one fluid column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I need to create a two column layout ([Online Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rDzbpDchYYshyk5sY1EF?p=preview)):

```
<header>
  A<br/>
  B<br/>
</header>    
<main>      
  <div class="wrapper">
    Vis iriure laboramus at. Quis audire ei vis ...
  </div>      
</main>
```

1. Header width must be fixed;
2. Main width must be fluid (%) width a maximum width in pixels;
3. Header and main heights must be 100%.

I tried the following CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} // *

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;    
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;  
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 44px;
  float: left;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -44px;
  max-width: 400px;  
  width: 100%;          
  float: left; 
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 88px;          
  padding: 24px;  
}
```

However, header and main are not 100% height.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

**UPDATE 1**
The code of the [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876335/2-columns-fixed-fluid-with-100-height) does not work!

Check the same code but with more text:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xM0BnHbF5Dh08EvrGY2V?p=preview

See, how text gets out of the wrapper ...

**UPDATE 2**
I added a menu on the left. 
Move the mouse hover the items "A", "B", etc to see how it should work.
The menu is working fine ... I would like to no break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:
http://codepen.io/awesomeaniruddh/pen/bdJBZy

Add the following piece of code:

```
html {
    height: 100%:
}
```

Before the html, body {..} part.

Comment: That does not solve it ... Check the update example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rDzbpDchYYshyk5sY1EF?p=preview. See how content gets out of main?

Comment: Replacing height with min-height solves the issue, but then the header with the red background stops showing up. The links with the blue background still show up though. Is that OK?

Comment: ...That is not perfect but it is better. However, there is one problem with your min-height solution. When the text in main is small main height will not be 100%. Check it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLNrwd?editors=110. That is one of the problems I have been trying to solve when using min-height.

Comment: http://codepen.io/awesomeaniruddh/pen/KpYypd?editors=110

That fixes that problem as well. I added `position: absolute` to both aside and main, and `left: 44px;` to main.

Comment: Pretty close but not quite ... when you resize the window to less than 400 pixels the main should resize and it is not. Check it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNoVem?editors=110

Comment: http://codepen.io/awesomeaniruddh/pen/XbQqzo works.

http://codepen.io/awesomeaniruddh/full/XbQqzo/ for a demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86936/discussion-between-aniruddh-agarwal-and-miguel).

Answer (score 1):

In line 6, simply remove `// *` and your code will work fine!

Comment: Damn, I didn't catch that! You have sharp eyes!

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal thanks:D

Comment: That was a typo but removing the comment does not solve the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/rDzbpDchYYshyk5sY1EF?p=preview. In this link you will see that the text, when it is long, comes out of the main tag. And the body and html do not fill the entire page. The solution to that is to add overflow: hidden to body ... But then I am not able to scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a two column layout...
>   1. Header width must be fixed;

If you want a columnar layout, why are you using a `header`. If you intend to use this block as your navigation in a sidebar, why not use a `nav` or `aside` which would be more semantic.

> 2. Main width must be fluid (%) width a maximum width in %

But in your css you are specifying `width: 100%` and then `max-width` in pixels,  and also a `margin` of `44px`.. why?

Just remove the `width` and `margin-right`, and only keep `max-width` in percent.

> 3. Header and main heights must be 100%

That's fine in your code. But, there are superfluous rules there. Just remove your heights from `html` and `body` and specify your two columns with a height of `100vh`.

> See, how text gets out of the wrapper ...

Of course, you haven't specified what to do when content goes out-of-bounds. You need to specify what `overflow` property you need on your `wrapper`.

***See these changes in your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4eKxAiJiKgthhMJJ31t?p=preview***

*Also, I can't undestand why you have a `wrapper` inside your `main`. It seems redundant and of no use.*

Comment: Still not working ... 1. I agree that must be aside and not header; 2 - max-width is in percentage ... That was a typo. (2 & 4): There is a reason for having margin of 44px and a wrapper. If you remove this when you decrease the browser width the main will become under aside and not side by side. Finally, I don't want to have scrollbars on main ... I want to have scrooll bars on the page.

Comment: What is not working? (1) There is no problem of main coming under aside on resize. (2) In this layout you cannot have scrollbars on main. Otherwise your aside will also scroll. (3) I have updated the plunker without the margin -  http://plnkr.co/edit/x4eKxAiJiKgthhMJJ31t?p=preview

Comment: I do not mind aside to scroll ... I only need it to have 44px width. I need main height to be 100% and it would be nice aside height to also be 100% even if not necessary. Main width should be fluid and not larger than, let's say, 400px. The space not covered with main or aside should have a differente background-color.

Comment: Basically, if you check http://plnkr.co/edit/rDzbpDchYYshyk5sY1EF?p=preview all I need to to make main fill the entire height and if possible, not necessary, the same for the aside. I want the scroll to be applied to page. Does this make sense?